# Why does collectstatic copy to wrong directory?

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

I thought I understood static files, collectstatic, etc. But this has my head spinning:

In `settings.py`:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

Then I run

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Then I see

```
You have requested to collect static files at the destination
location as specified in your settings:

    D:\Code\Project\staticfiles
```

I'm pretty sure at one point I did actually use 'staticfiles'. But now I've changed it to 'static' and it still thinks the destination should be staticfiles. I've deleted the `__pycache__` folder and it still doesn't work.

[Updates]
I do have a custom settings file. I based it off of Two Scoops where there is a settings folder with a base.py settings and local.py and production.py. I'm running local and local.py only has db creds and DEBUG = True.

I don't have any value for STATICFILES_STORAGE.

If I `print` STATIC_ROOT I see:

```
D:\Code\Project\static
```

[UPDATE]
I'm now looking at the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py). self.storage.location on line 161 is imported on line 5 from django.contrib.staticfiles.storage. In storage.py it is set equal to ConfiguredStorage() on line 442. ConfiguredStorage() inherits a class called LazyObject and has a single function called _setup. This is where the trail gets cold for me. I am trying to find out how self.storage.location is defined. But I can't figure out which way to go now - how do I follow the breadcrumbs back to how STATIC_ROOT?

Comment: Do you have custom settings files?

Comment: What is the value of `settings.STATICFILES_STORAGE` ?

Comment: What does STATIC_ROOT output if you print it in a python console?

Comment: Thanks all - I just updated my question with responses to you.

Comment: @LiamHanninen Can you put your project on GitHub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have two settings, one for production and one for development, you may need to specify the settings module while running the **`collectstatic`** command by using **`--settings`** flag.
So, try this

```
python manage.py collectstatic --settings=path.to.settings.module
```

---

## UPDATE-1

### Issue

The issue was in this statement,
[**`django_heroku.settings(locals())`**](https://github.com/Liamhanninen/stranderspublic/blob/master/settings/base.py#L153)

That particular statement takes all the local variables (which is the `local()`) and ***create necessary settings for your project***.
[In that module, we can see these statements](https://github.com/heroku/django-heroku/blob/master/django_heroku/core.py#L92-L96),

> ```
> if staticfiles:
>     logger.info('Applying Heroku Staticfiles configuration to Django settings.')
>
>     config['STATIC_ROOT'] = os.path.join(config['BASE_DIR'], 'staticfiles')
>     config['STATIC_URL'] = '/static/'
> ```

Which means, **`django_heroku`** package will set a **`STATIC_ROOT`** value for you if you don't have one. (Yeah, you don't have a `STATIC_ROOT` in your **`base.py`**)

### Solution

#### Case 1: Separate `STATIC_ROOT` for local and production settings

Just overwrite the value of **`STATIC_ROOT`** in corresponding settings modules as,

```
#settings/local.py
STATIC_ROOT = 'static_root_for_local/'

#settings/production.py
STATIC_ROOT = 'static_root_for_production/'
```

#### Case 2: Same `STATIC_ROOT` for all settings

```
# settings/base.py
# other settings variable
django_heroku.settings(locals())

STATIC_ROOT = 'common_static_root/'  # this statement should be after the "django_heroku.settings(locals())"
```

Comment: No luck. Darn I thought for sure this would do it.

Comment: Oops... I couldn't reproduce the error. Is there any way to reproduce the error?

Comment: Not that I know of. I just finished installing Django Scheduler which involves changing STATICFILES_FINDERS. So maybe something to do with that. Also please check out my most recent Update about my look into the source code. Thanks.

Comment: can you add your codebase to somewhere like GitHub?

Comment: Sure thing. Do I just need to remove my db creds and secret key? Anything else?

Comment: Yeah. but in short, anything sensitive :)

Comment: Where did you put this line of code, **`STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')`**? I couldn't find it on the codebase.

Comment: Line 123 in settings/base.py. It's commented out because I was trying different ideas.

Comment: After 3 hours of useless struggle, I found out that Django heroku was overwriting my static root. Thank you so much.